# Data not loading in programmatically created tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create an extremely simple app without using storyboards for the first time.

I am just trying to display a tableView as my first screen once the app loads. I create a UIView class and then create a table view in the viewDidLoad method.

Within my delegate class I create an instance of my class, and then set it as my root view controller.

When I run the app, the tableView displays, but the cells do not display the numbers on them. I have been reading the apple documentation on this but have not found a solution so far. It may be very small but I can't seem to figure it out.

As you can see I create an array filled with very simple strings that are just numbers. I want each number to display on a cell in the table view, but when the tableview loads the cells are blank.

```
#import "NumbersViewController.h"

@interface NumbersViewController ()

@end

@implementation NumbersViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [tableView reloadData];

    self.view = tableView;

    self.numArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"1"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"2"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"3"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"4"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"5"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"6"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"7"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"8"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"9"];



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Number of rows is the number of time zones in the region for the specified section.

    return [self.numArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *number = [self.numArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = number;
    return cell;
}



@end
```

Comment: FYI - there is no need to call `reloadData` on the table in the `viewDidLoad` method. BTW - why aren't you simply using a `UITableViewController`? If your table view is full screen sized, that would be the better choice.

Comment: @rmaddy Is it actually considered bad practice to use a `UIViewController` in place of a `UITableViewController` when the table view is full screen sized? I choose to do `UIViewControllers` just in case the UI/UX needs change and the `tableview` is no longer screen sized. Just curious if this is actually frowned upon.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using `UIViewController`. It's just easier to use `UITableViewController` if the only view will be the table view.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but this implementation is surprising. You are creating your view in `-viewDidLoad`, a method called *after* your controller's view has been created. In this case you're relying on the default implementation of `-loadView` to create an empty UIView and then replacing it. It would make more sense to override `-loadView` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add data after you `reloadData`

```
//Delegate methods called
[tableView reloadData];

self.view = tableView;

// data added
self.numArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[self.numArray addObject:@"1"];
```

**Solution**
Move `numArray` initialization & seeding code above `reloadData`

Comment: This would be a better answer if you provided a solution and not just point out the problem.

Comment: @rmaddy I think the solution is obvious? Make some sample data and then `reloadData`?:)

Comment: In this case the solution is clear once you point out the problem but in general, a good answer on SO explains the issue and provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

call Table Reload after setting values into array

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    self.view = tableView;

    self.numArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"1"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"2"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"3"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"4"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"5"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"6"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"7"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"8"];
    [self.numArray addObject:@"9"];

    [tableView reloadData];

}
```